# variable "context" might not have been initialized, java JNDI util

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, pmd

I am currently working on a project for a company, and we have taken an open-source family tree project from Microsoft (The source function can be found here: [Family History](https://familyhistory.hhs.gov/fhh-web/home.action) and the source code on their [GForge](http://gforge.nci.nih.gov/projects/fhh)), but I've run into issues the whole time. I've solve most compilation errors for the most part, because they were simple exception errors, but this one is one I haven't been able to solve yet. I've Googled the problem and found many similar solutions, but none seem to work quite right. If you need any more information please let me know, I'll do my best to try and provide it to you. Although, I am still a beginner in java.

The compiler (which is a Apache Maven 2.2.1) gives me the following error:

```
C:\mfhp-2.4.0\services\src\main\java\gov\hhs\fhh\service\locator\JndiUtil.java:
[68,4] variable context might not have been initialized
```

Here is the code for the file:

```
public final class JndiUtil {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JndiUtil.class);
private static final String RESOURCE_NAME = "jndi.properties";

private static JndiUtil theInstance = new JndiUtil();

private final InitialContext context;

private JndiUtil() {
    try {
        Properties props = getProperties();
        context = new InitialContext(props);
    } catch (NamingException e) { //This was a fix I did
        LOG.error("Unable to initialize the JNDI Util.", e);
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    } catch (IOException ioe) { //This was a fix I did
    LOG.error("IOException", ioe);
    }
}

/**
 * @return jndi (& jms) properties
 * @throws IOException on class load error
 */
public static Properties getProperties() throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(JndiUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_NAME));
    return props;
}

/**
 * @param name name to lookup
 * @return object in default context with given name
 */
public static Object lookup(String name) {
    return lookup(theInstance.context, name);
}

/**
 * @param ctx context
 * @param name name to get
 * @return object in contect with given name
 */
public static Object lookup(InitialContext ctx, String name) {
    try {
        return ctx.lookup(name);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        //LOG.error("------------------Here is what's in the context--(looking for " + name + ")----------");
        LOG.error("------------------Error looking up ctx context for: " + name + ")----------");
        //dump(ctx, 0);
        //LOG.error("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}
/*
 * Method taken out to avoid looping messages into log file
private static void dump(javax.naming.Context ctx, int indent) {
    try {
        NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> en = ctx.list("");
        while (en.hasMore()) {
            NameClassPair ncp = en.next();
            String cn = ncp.getClassName();
            String n = ncp.getName();
            LOG.info("\t\t\t\t\t\t".substring(0, indent) + n + " : " + cn);
            try {
                Object o = ctx.lookup(n);
                if (o instanceof Context) {
                    dump((Context) o, indent + 1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.info(e);
            }
        }
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        LOG.info(ex);
    }
}
*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`context` must be initialized by the time the constructor is done, because it's a `final` field.

If `Properties props = getProperties();` happens to throw an exception, then `context` will not be initialized by the time the constructor ends. The exception will be caught (by the "fix" you implemented), handled and processing will continue. Essentially, your "fix" caused your class' constructor to end successfully even if `context` isn't initialized.

Comment: Oh okay, hmm... So both of the exceptions I supposedly caught should be removed and put back to catching general exceptions? I had to change it because I got PMD errors from Maven, and it also told me that instead of catching generic exceptions, to catch NamingExceptions.

Comment: Well, what you do with it depends on what you're expecting `JndiUtil` to do. If I were you, I would declare `JndiUtil`'s constructor so it has `NamingException` and `IOException` in its "throws" clause, and avoid handling exceptions within the constructor.

Comment: So, your original code caught a generic exception and wrapped it with an `IllegalStateException`. That caused a PMD error because your PMD is configured to advise against catching generic exceptions. If you want to maintain the design, and still satisfy your current PMD configuration, you should catch the explicit exceptions (`IOException` and `NamingException`). If you use JDK 7, you can do `catch (IOException | NamingException e)`.

Comment: Sorry about deleting the comments. When I repost my question the code format came out weird. So I apologize about that. I will try it and thank you for your prompt replies and help!

Comment: I tried removing my old catches and replacing it with the catch you mentioned, but I'm getting a newer error in my checkstyles.

`private JndiUtil() {
  try {
  Properties props = getProperties();
  context = new InitialContext(props);
 } catch (IOException | javax.naming.NamingException e) {
  LOG.error("Unable to initialize the JNDI Util.", e);
  throw new IllegalStateException(e);
 }
}`
            Checkstyle:
`<file name="JndiUtil.java">
<error line="63" column="13" severity="error" message="Got an exception - expecting EOF, found &apos;throw&apos;"`

Comment: I'm sorry, the error is with the `throw new IllegalStateException(e);` the word New seems to not be liked.

Comment: That's probably because you're not using JDK 7 to compile. As I mentioned in my comment above, only JDK 7 supports a multi-exception `catch` block. If you're using JDK 6 or below, you will have to create two different `catch` blocks, one for each exception.

Comment: Hmm.. So I changed it to JDK 7, I didn't realize it was using the 1.5 compiler. (I have older versions of JDK on my computer) and after updating everything, nesting the catch statement, I still get the same original error. I read around some more and most say to put the value to `null`, I have tried this with no luck.